# adding field to django user model - how to automatically create object instance?

Tags: django, django-models

I am attempting to add a field 'balance' to the default django user model, and i've done so with this code:

```
class UserBalance(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    balance = models.IntegerField(default=0)
```

but my problem is that when I create a new user, I need to manually add a value for the balance in the django admin console otherwise I can't use it in html template tags, whereas I want it to just automatically be created and added as 0 to the user's profile once they create it. What is the easiest way to do this?

[User account that I manually added balance via admin console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1Zf2W.png)
[User account freshly created](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xNRBH.png)

Answer (score 0):

What you've done is almost right, you just need to create a signal that would trigger a creation of a "UserBalance" instance.

To do this, you could use Django Signals like so:

```
# Imports
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.db.models.signals import post_save
from django.dispatch import receiver

# Models
class UserBalance(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    balance = models.IntegerField(default=0)

# Signals
@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def create_user_balance(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        UserBalance.objects.create(user=instance)
```

The function "create_user_balance" is called whenever a User instance gets created or modified. Since you want to create an instance only when a User is created, the receiver sends a boolean parameter "created" that specifies that.

Hope this helps.